# Slow performance of Excel Interop in worker thread

Tags: c#, excel, multithreading, excel-interop

I have encountered very slow performance of Excel Interop in Worker Thread.

Here is my code in VSTO project, that just reads a value of specified cell (e.g. 'Sheet1!A1'):

```
    private object test(string sheetRange = "Sheet1!A1")
    {
        var targetRange = sheetRange.Split('!');
        if (targetRange.Length != 2) { return null; }

        var sheetname = targetRange[0];
        var address = targetRange[1];
        var workbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook;

        var sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[sheetname];
        var cell = sheet.Range[address];

        return cell.Value;
    }
```

When I run this code in UI thread, it works quite fast.
But once it is run in worker thread, the performance is quite terrible (about x50 - x100 slower).

```
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            test();
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join(int.MaxValue);
```

*Marshal.ReleaseComObject is not perfomed, because this is a test code.*

Is there any bad points in my code?
OR is there any way to avoid performance problem in worker thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are crossing the COM boundary between two STA threads. COM has to marshal all of the calls, which can be very costly.

If you *must* have Excel-related logic in a different thread than the one that owns your original Excel object(s), then you should do the marshaling yourself. I.e. do whatever background logic you need to in that worker thread, but make sure that when you interact with the Excel object, you get back onto the owning thread, with whatever data you need to make the calls to the Excel object, so that your calls can go directly to the Excel COM server code instead of being marshaled.

Comment: Finally I use ``SynchronizationContext`` to make Excel-related logic performed in main thread.